# How can I put lat value inside markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
$.getJSON('map_points.json', function(data) { 
  $.each( data.points, function(i, value) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon),
      map: map,
      title: " text " +  value.lat
    });
  });
});
```

I have make marker using `map_points.json` file using `lat`, `lon` value in `data_points.json` file. Now I want `lat` value display inside that each maker in my google map.

Comment: What is the problem here? It doesn't display the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('map_points.json', function(data) { 
        $.each( data.points, function(i, value) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon),
            map: map,
            title: " Latitude: " +  value.lat+" Longiude: "+value.lon//here is the difference
            });

            //add info window
            var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                     content:  "Latitude: " +  value.lat+" Longiude: "+value.lon
             });
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) { iw.open(map, this); });
        });

});
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Added a comment on the changed line !

Comment: It is a change of text. Not sure if that is going to help OP.

Comment: Then please accept my answer as a correct one. That can help other users to find the correct answer. :)

Comment: But, how can i add this latitude and longiude value inside marker?  not need to point in that marker?

Comment: Sorry ! but not getting you clearly ! Please elaborate your problem

Comment: It shows latitude and logitude when i point to that marker..but i need it automatically display latitude and longitude on that marker when i load my  google map

Comment: I have edited my code and added info window code. Try this and let me know

Comment: //add info window
            var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                     content:  "Latitude: " +  value.lat+" Longiude: "+value.lon
             });
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) { iw.open(map, this); }); //it works for me...thanks very much for ur answer for a beginner in programming